# How can I get "smooth" scrolling in ListView on Android

Tags: android, listview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using Appcelerator to developer cross platform native apps.

I have a small annoying issue that I think should be possible to solve - but so far I have not been able to find a solution. Having dived into this I can see that having a `swipe` event handler defined will cause a `<ListView>` (or `<ScrollView>`) to scroll very ***sticky*** (instead of smooth).

A simple sample:

**View:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <View>
            <Label id="label">My list...</Label>
            <ListView id="nameList" defaultItemTemplate="templateName" onItemclick="onSelect">
                <Templates>
                    <ItemTemplate name="templateName">
                        <Label bindId="name"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </Templates>
                <ListSection>
                    <ListItem/>
                </ListSection>
            </ListView>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**Style:**

```
".container": {
    top: 20,
    backgroundColor:"white",
    orientationModes: [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT]
}
"Label": {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    left:10, 
    color: "#000"
}

"#label": { top:15, 
    font: {
        fontSize: '18dp',
        fontStyle: 'bold'
    }
}

"#nameList":{
    top:'50dp'
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function onSelect(e) {
    var section = $.nameList.sections[e.sectionIndex];
    var item = section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
   console.log("index=" + e.itemIndex + ", item: " +JSON.stringify(item));
}

var list = [];
for(var i=0; i<50; i++){
    var item = {template: "templateName",name : { text: "Item " + i }};
    list.push(item);
}

console.log("Set list items");
$.nameList.sections[0].items = list;

$.index.open();

$.index.addEventListener('swipe',function(e){
    console.log("... swiped: " + JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

...and then run this app on an Android device (I did on an Android 6 device - but issue seen on other Android versions).

Anyone knows a way to remove the "stickiness"?

/John

***Edit:**

*I have found one difference that may be the root cause of this. If I scroll up/down on an iPhone it does NOT trigger the `swipe` event. However, on Android it DOES trigger the event....*

Comment: I really dont want to know how that "appcelerator" works, that looks like javascript... but ListView should have a method called smoothScrollToPosition()

Comment: It better to use RecyclerView.If you want to use Listview then use ViewHolder inside your custom Adapter